# Adobe Air apps on the Mac App Store?

Tags: apple

Before you chastise me for asking this, I have an Adobe Air app that has a lot of investment in it, and if there is a way to utilize the existing code-base in *any* way, it is worth considering.

I have heard news reports in passing about Adobe creating some kind of tool to allow flash or air apps to be ported to native objective-c code, but the information found in google is mostly commentary on the one-time Apple blockade.

My question(s) is/are this:

1. Is it even possible, at any level, to use an existing Air app to create a Mac Store app?
2. If possible, what are the resources I can use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Historically, AIR applications failed several of the [Mac App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/mac/resources/approval/guidelines.html):

> - Apps that download or install additional code or resources to add functionality or change their primary purpose will be rejected
> - Apps must be packaged and submitted using Apple's packaging technologies included in Xcode - no third party installers allowed
> - Apps must be self-contained, single application installation bundles, and cannot install code or resources in shared locations
> - Apps that use deprecated or optionally installed technologies (e.g., Java, Rosetta) will be rejected

And the [Flash Packager for iPhone](http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/packagerforiphone.html) is for iOS applications, not Mac applications.

However, as [Resist Design noted](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/150441/8), Adobe has released [a version of the AIR runtime](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4380335) with the explicit goal of getting AIR apps approved for the Mac App Store:

> **Improved Mac App Store Support** — Added support to ensure Mac AIR apps adhere to Apple guidelines and can be submitted to the Mac App store successfully.

Given this is relatively new development and Apple's App Store Review Guidelines are—to quote them—a "living document", your mileage may vary when submitting AIR-based apps to the Mac App Store for approval.

Comment: If you want to submit AIR Apps, there is Adobe AIR MarketPlace.

Comment: Playing devils advocate, Air apps produce a .app binary, If I submit that, how would apple know what created it? I think the only violation of the 4 you posted is the 2nd one right?

Comment: @coneybeare 1) It's pretty obvious after using an Air app for a few minutes that it's an Air app: Adobe doesn't provide native access to Cocoa controls. 2) Air app bundles have multiple Air signatures 3) Air apps can't be run without the Adobe Air runtime, and prompt the user to download and install Air when first run (thus fail 1, 3, and 4 of the highlighted points)

Comment: It seems to me that the use of AIR 3 and Captive Runtime would make an AIR app that will fulfill Apple's Guidelines for Mac store submission.

Answer (score 0):

There is a application called Elips from Open Plug which translates flex/flash source code into objective C. It's designed to allow flash applications to be ported to iPhone. You will probably need to write your mac user interace in native xcode but you should be able to translate large chunks of back-end code then debug/compile for mac.